# KivyMD как задать цвет текста и фона?

Tags: python, kivy

KivyMD как задать цвет текста и фона?
Подскажите пожалуйста, гугление не помогает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бэкграунд фона:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Цвет текста(.kv файл):

```
<RootLayout>:
    rows: 1
    Label:
        text: "text"
        color: 1,0,1,1
```

Comment: Это хорошо, но в моем случае я использовал библиотеку kivyMD и как оказалось использовал не квадратные, а круглые кнопки. Вот в чем была проблема md_bg_color: [0,0,0,1]

Answer (score 1):

в коде:

```
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

bx_content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", padding=["5sp", "5sp"])
lbl_trn = MDLabel(
    text=current_trn, md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex("#06483a"),
    theme_text_color="Custom", text_color=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
    size_hint_y = None, height = standard_line_height, halign="center")
    
bx_content.add_widget(lbl_trn)

card_background = MDCard(md_bg_color=get_color_from_hex("#146252"), padding=["5sp", "5sp"])
bx_content.add_widget(card_main_background)
```

в file.kv:

```
MDCard:
    md_bg_color: .5, .5, .5, 1

MDLabel:
    id: my_label
    md_bg_color: .7, .7, .7, 1
```

Изменение элемента по id из file.kv

```
self.screen_manager.get_screen("my_screen").ids.my_label.md_bg_color = .7, 0, 0, 1
```

Comment: Ухх, уже даже и не смогу проверить. Давно этим не занимался